# What do you mean by dispatch function and forwarding function in Boost.Python?

Tags: python, c++, boost, virtual, overriding

Can anyone help me in understanding of what are dispatch functions and forwarding functions mean in Boost Python while overriding a class member function and creating the wrapper around base class?

The example for same can be found at:

[Virtual Functions with Default Implementations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html#python.virtual_functions_with_default_implementations)

Here is the example which works fine without need for Forwarding function:

```
class Base
{
    public:
virtual void xfoo(int i)
    {
        cout << "XFOO::BASE" << i;
    }

        Base(){}
        Base(const Base&){}
};

class BaseW : public Base, public wrapper<Base>
{
    public:
    void xfoo(int i)
    {
        if(override f= this->get_override("xfoo"))
        {
            f();
        }
        Base::xfoo(i);
    }

};

class BaseImpl : public Base
{
    public:
    void xfoo(int i)
    {
        cout << "xFoo:Der " << i;
    }
};
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    class_<BaseW, boost::noncopyable >("Base")
        .def("xfoo",&Base::xfoo)
        ;
    class_<BaseImpl, bases<Base> >("BaseImpl");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "dispatch function" is the implementation which "switches" on the derived class type to find out which implementation of a virtual function should execute.  Like a pure virtual function.  The "forwarding function" seems to refer to the default (base class) implementation of the virtual function.

I too find this terminology a bit confusing.  But it's only used in passing in the Boost documentation, and I don't think it's very important in the grand scheme of things.  Try not to get hung up on it.

Comment: Knowingly that "dispatch function" switched to appropiate implementation of virtual function, why it can't select the base class default implementation by itsellf, and thereby why need for forwading function. I have tested with sample code without having "forwarding function" with inheritance hirearchy and exposed same to python. It was working fine. I am still not clear with need of "Forwarding function"

Comment: Maybe it's in case there is no base class implementation (i.e. it's pure virtual)?  I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I have virtual function in base with default implementation. And its overrided in Derrived class. The same hirearchy is exposed to python.